# Angular CLI with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, angular, spring-boot, angular-cli

I have 2 projects. An Angular2 app which I build with Angular-cli and a Spring Boot app which will only serve the Angular2 app. I build the Angular2 app with `ng build` which generates a `dist` folder. I then put the content of the `dist` folder in the Spring Boot app inside `src/main/resources/static`.

My spring boot app has two files.

The Spring boot application class :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBoot.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBoot.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the application.properties file:

```
server.contextPath=/
server.port=80
```

It works well but if I go to an url and hit the refresh button, I get the `Whitelabel Error Page`. I know it's because the URLs are not serving the `index.html` when they don't match a resource file.

How can I configure my Spring Boot app to serve `index.html` if the url doesn't match a resource file?

Comment: Using a servlet filter, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that `index.html` needs to be served back for endpoints unknown to Spring. Then arrange for the Angular app to manage unknown routes.

I handle this situation with a `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. Also put static content file types in here.

Add a `config` directory and in it add a Java file `WebMvcConfig` (for example) with this content:

```java
package com.yourdomain.yourapp.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ ResourceProperties.class })
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Inject
  private ResourceProperties resourceProperties = new ResourceProperties();

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    Integer cachePeriod = resourceProperties.getCachePeriod();

    final String[] staticLocations = resourceProperties.getStaticLocations();
    final String[] indexLocations = new String[staticLocations.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < staticLocations.length; i++) {
      indexLocations[i] = staticLocations[i] + "index.html";
    }
    registry.addResourceHandler(
      "/**/*.css",
      "/**/*.html",
      "/**/*.js",
      "/**/*.json",
      "/**/*.bmp",
      "/**/*.jpeg",
      "/**/*.jpg",
      "/**/*.gif",
      "/**/*.ico",
      "/**/*.png",
      "/**/*.ttf",
      "/**/*.wav",
      "/**/*.mp3",
      "/**/*.eot",
      "/**/*.svg",
      "/**/*.woff",
      "/**/*.woff2",
      "/**/*.map"
    )
      .addResourceLocations(staticLocations)
      .setCachePeriod(cachePeriod);

    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
      .addResourceLocations(indexLocations)
      .setCachePeriod(cachePeriod)
      .resourceChain(true)
      .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
        @Override
        protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
          return location.exists() && location.isReadable() ? location : null;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

I think you will also have to specify the config package for component scan. Maybe try without first and see if it works.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan( basePackages = { "com.yourdomain.yourapp.config" })
public class SpringBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SpringBoot.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBoot.class, args);
  }
}
```

In case your missing dependencies. This is what I have in my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
  compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'

  optional group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor'

  providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

  testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you! It worked without specifying the config package for component scan.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/milanhlinak/spring-boot-angular-starter) you can find my Spring Boot 2 and Angular 6 starter project.

Spring Boot application is created using [SPRING INITIALIZR](https://start.spring.io/), Angular application is created using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/).